# Why am I getting a "expected '}' but found '{'" error in dotless?

Tags: css, less, dotless

I have tried to append the values using +_ in less, but it throws the error

> expected '}' but found '{'

in the dotless compiler. What did I miss?

```
.gradient(@brow){      
    @{brow}+_: ~"; background: @{brow}linear-gradient(top";
     // some content
  }
}
```

The error indicates in this lineL `@{brow}+_:`.

Comment: Isn't there one `}` too many in your snippet? There's 3 `{`, but 4 `}`. And `(top` seems to be missing the closing parenthesis